# Who to contact about an outdated application in the Software center?

Tags: software-center

Sometimes applications in the Software Center are outdated and several years old. For instance the version of QtGain is several years old.

Who should I contact to report this?

Answer (score 3):

You will actually want file a "needs packaging" bug and contact the package maintainer, not the developer of the software (although sometimes they are the same person).

The 'needs packaging' bug will need to be filed on [launchpad](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu) against Ubuntu

To find the package maintainer, you can either search for the package on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ or from the command line with

```
apt-cache show <packagename>
```

You could then send the maintainer an email with the bug number.

Comment: +1 More precise than me! Unless the maintainer is packed and gone, of course, as can be the case in software that has only a small audience.

Answer (score 1):

The developer of the software. For very old projects, they may not be interested in updating the application, in that case you could look for an alternative (or fix it yourself :)

In the case of QtGain, though, it seems to have been updated only a few months ago, and there is some sort of support thread on [the QtGain page at QtApps.org](http://qt-apps.org/content/show.php?content=56842). The developer is known as [Vegeta](http://qt-apps.org/usermanager/search.php?username=Vegeta), and the only way to contact him seems to be through the afore-mentioned thread.

Note that the versions of applications in the Software Center (or the repo) are often not the very latest ones; in case of large gaps between the latest version and the in-repo version, you should contact the package's maintainer, or simply use the latest version and bypass the Software Center / package manager entirely (for that software).

Comment: IMHO, it's better to look for an alternative than contacting the developer of the software, unless there is none. You don't want the pain of having to contact the developer every time something breaks as if you are the lone user of the app.

Comment: Not all developers are the packagers of their software, so it's better to look up the package maintainer rather than the developer.

Comment: I've emailed apachelogger who is supposed to be the maintainer. No answer yet though.